# Como funciona o openssl_encrypt para o método AES-256-CBC com uma chave menor que 16 caracteres?

Tags: php, openssl

Um cliente usa a criptografia AES-256-CBC em um sistema PHP usando openssl_encrypt e eu preciso realizar a mesma operação em um sistema utilizando C#.

Contudo, a chave que ele informa tem apenas 12 caracteres e em C# não é permitido informar uma chave com menos que 16 caracteres. Consultando na internet vi que a quantidade de caracteres exigida é de 16 caracteres devido a quantidade de bytes para a chave desse método de criptografia.

No sistema atual, o método funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
function crypto($str)
{
    $key = "123456789012";
    $iv = "1234567890123456";
    $method = 'AES-256-CBC';

    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, $method, $key, true, $iv));
}
```

A minha dúvida é: como a função openssl_encrypt faz para completar a quantidade de bytes exigidos para esse método de criptografia recebendo uma chave menor?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("minha senha");
if (key.Length < 32)
{
    var paddedkey = new byte[32];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 0, paddedkey, 0, key.Length);
    key = paddedkey;
}
```

E essa Key para como parâmetro para o CreateEncryptor.

Comment: Ficando claro que isso está criando uma chave mais fraca que o esperado, tá valendo.